# I couldn't get transitions to work on div element(square), anybody has any idea why?

Tags: html, css, css-transitions, css-grid

**HTML**

```html
    <html>
    <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./style.css" />
    <title>Document</title>
    </head>
    <body>
    <div class="container">
     <div class="square"></div>
    </div>
    </body>
    </html>
```

**CSS**
With the following CSS rule:

```css
   .container {
      display: grid;
      grid-template-columns: repeat(10, 40px);
      grid-template-rows: repeat(10, 40px);
      column-gap: 10px;
      row-gap: 10px;
    }
    .square {
      grid-row: 5 / 8;
      grid-column: 4 / 8;
      transition: all 5s ease;
    }
    .square:hover {
      grid-row: 2 / 6;
      grid-column: 2 / 6;
    }
```

The code is not working, the square div is changing grid-row and grid-column but there is no transition effect, while grid change.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is, that `grid-row` and `grid-column` are not animatable.

On mdn web docs is a [list of animatable CSS properties](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_animated_properties).